# DIV fixa + DIV rolagem automatica

Tags: html, css

Estou fazendo um pequeno chat, e estou tendo problemas com a barra de rolagem. Eu quero que fique o scroll na principal, e não no `iframe`.

*Imagem:*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*HTML:*

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
         <form action="chat.php" method="post">
            <div class="tudo" style=" "><iframe src="interacao.php" width="100%" height="1000px" style="border:1px red solid;" frameborder="0" ></iframe></div>
            <div class="texto" style="width:100%; "><?php require_once("writing.php"); ?></div>
         </form>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Olá marconi. Obrigado por responder. :) https://jsfiddle.net/28myouf2/ segue o css.

Answer (score 2):

Por default, o overflow começa com o valor **visible**.

Tente isso: (esconder o scroll)

```
style="border:1px red solid;overflow:hidden;"
```

Retire trecho height="1000px".

E adicione isso ao seu css:

```
style="... min-height:1000px;height:auto;"
```

O que fizemos foi:

definir um tamanho minimo para o frame(caso você queira) e deixar o tamanho máximo automático, com o trecho **height:auto**;

Comment: certo. tente isso amigo: scrolling="no".

Comment: Geovane, terminei apagando invez de editar o comentario acima. desculpe. Acabei de fazer o scrolling="no" e funcionou perfeitamente. muito obrigado por compartilhar!!!! :)

Comment: @JoaoMarcos se alguma das respostas for valida, considere validá-la clicando no icon verde abaixo das setas de validação...

Comment: Magic, não aparece seta verde. =\ coloquei como resposta util! :)

Comment: Por nada amigo ;). Lembrando que o  scrolling="no" só funcionará em alguns browser. Por isso, é interessante que você mantenha as duas soluções.

Comment: @JoaoMarcos vai com o mouse que vai aparecer...

Comment: @JoaoMarcos não se esqueça de marcar a resposta como correta. Pois ela pode ajudar outros também.